# How to check whether a correlation is actually temporal or spatial?

Tags: qgis, python, spatial-statistics, spatio-temporal-data, autocorrelation

I have two variables `probability (of a fire)` and `temperature` between 2001 and 2018 over multiple grid cells. When I look at the correlation through a simple Spearman it seems good (p = 0.01, r = 0.8). However, someone pointed out that time and space may influence this correlation, and potentially one more than the other e.g. spatial more influential than temporal.

Is there a way to look the influence of spatial and temporal correlation on the correlation of the probability and temperature?

Comment: How did you build the probability variable?  Temperature, precipitation, relative humidity, wind speed are seasonal (temporal dependent). Dead and live fuel materials and topography could be considered  spatial dependent. For instance, you can run the correlation for Summer season where high temperatures and low relative humidity both  favor fires.  The correlation coefficient will be even better?

Comment: Yes, the probability variable includes all of the variables mentioned here. But doing the correlation for differents seasons will not tell me a lot about how the correlation between `probability` and `temperature` can be influenced by time and space.